# React-markdown not working properly - Module "process" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "process.cwd" in client code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, react-markdown

I'm working with the library react-markdown for the ease this gives at dealing with markdown files and content. But now I'm experiencing an unexpected error and tbh I do not really know how to solve it.

I'll insert the code below to see if I can get any help

**LessonMd.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";


const LessonMd: React.FC = () => {
  return (<div><ReactMarkdown>{`#Test one ##not working`}</ReactMarkdown></div>);
};

export default LessonMd;
```

**App.tsx**

```
function App(): JSX.Element {

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <LessonMd/>
            <TextEditor/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
browser-external:process:9 Uncaught Error: Module "process" has been externalized for browser compatibility. Cannot access "process.cwd" in client code.
    at Object.get (browser-external:process:9:13)
    at new VFile (index.js:119:21)
    at ReactMarkdown (react-markdown.js:97:16)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:13)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:16)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:7)
```

Comment: I [cannot reproduce the issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-react-markdown?file=src%2FLessonMd.tsx). As an aside, your markdown is invalid. You need a space after the `#`, and a new line between headings.